# Good text book recomendation

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, book-recommendation, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to do some reading about a technique called sequential convex programming. There is a lot of material about sequential quadratic programming out there, including books (Nocedal & Wright), papers and surveys but I couldn't find good resources about sequential convex programming/optimization. A textbook would be best. Otherwise a reference to a scientific paper could work out. Stephen Boyd has video lectures and useful slides on his website:

http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures.html

I am interested in particular in the special case where the subproblems (those you solve at each iteration) are second order cone programs. But a more general reference should be good enough.

Comment: The field is new enough that what you find on Google is the best you're likely to do.

Comment: I could only find this paper: 

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Moritz_Diehl/publication/226209221_Local_Convergence_of_Sequential_Convex_Programming_for_Nonconvex_Optimization/links/0deec525d3ecc89a8e000000.pdf

where in the abstract they claim to introduce sequential convex programming (SCP). This was published in 2010, while Boyd's videos seem to be from 2008, where SCP is already mentioned.
Is there another paper that introduce this method prior to 2010